# Click events stop working after replacing attribute of <use> element in <svg> (Win7/IE11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, svg

We are using multiple [svg symbols](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) for displaying icons.

```
<!-- defining them at the start of the page -->
<div id="icon-container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            id="rect" ...>
        <rect... />
    </symbol>

    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            id="circle" ...>
        <circle... />
    </symbol>
</svg>
</div>

<!-- using them in the page somewhere -->
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#rect"></use>
</svg>
```

In some cases we need to replace them later on with another icon (like on a collapse control), therefore I created a little helper function to change the `xlink:href` to the new symbol name.

```
$.fn.replaceSVGIcon = function(id) {
    $(this).find('svg')
           .andSelf()
           .filter('svg')
           .find('use')
           .attr('xlink:href', '#' + id);
}
```

This works in every browser except for IE10 + IE11 on Windows 7 (but weirdly enough it works with Windows 8).

When you open the snippet below in IE11 and click on the red box everything is fine, but as soon as you start clicking on the element within, it breaks the whole page after the icon is changed for the first time.

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.replaceSVGIcon = function(id) {
        $(this).find('svg').andSelf().filter('svg').find('use').attr('xlink:href', '#' + id);
    }
})(jQuery);

clickFunction = function() {
    var $elem = $('#icon');
    
    if ($elem.find('use').attr('xlink:href') == '#rect')
    {
        $elem.replaceSVGIcon('circle');
    } else {
        $elem.replaceSVGIcon('rect');
    }
};
```

```css
#icon-container {
    visibility: collapse;
    display: none;
}

#icon {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    fill: #454545;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="icon-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="rect" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <rect x="15" y="15" width="20" height="20"></rect>
        </symbol>
    
        <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="circle" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="10"></circle>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
</div>

<svg id="icon" onclick="clickFunction()">
    <rect fill="red" height="40" width="40"></rect>
    <use xlink:href="#rect"></use>
</svg>
```

Why is this happening and is this a known Internet Explorer bug? What are my options to work around this issue?

Comment: I'd start by maybe console logging each piece one at a time... make sure your click event is firing correclty, is it calling your plugin, what does it think `$(this)` is inside the plugin. Is andSelf working (I thought it was deprecated?), etc etc. You just have pigeon-hole the problem unfortunately :/

Comment: The problem is that the whole site (really everything) gets unclickable afterwards, also when I trigger the function from another element it works without a flaw.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is removing the `onClick=""` part. Make a normal jQuery `$('#whatever').on('click', function () { }` click event, and see if that helps any! I have a weird feeling IE is being bizarre like usual, and maybe losing the connection somehow

Comment: I've experienced weird issues with SVGs in IE.  We have code that checks for the existence of a correspondingUseElement property and forces an event on the parent.  Not sure if this is at all relevant to your case, but it's something like this: actualTarget = $(target[0].correspondingUseElement).parents('a').trigger('click');

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS it has the same effect, but `$(document).on('click', '#icon', function () { }` acutally stops the site from being unusable, but then only the red part is clickable and clicking on the containing element still does not work.

Comment: Isn't it `'#icon-container'` ? And yikes, if you have a live version I can look at, I can try and debug it, but otherwise, not sure I can help =(

Comment: just click "show code snippet" in my answer and you can run it, but I can make a fiddle if that's easier for you

Comment: here's a fiddle with all three ways to do it (second one is the only one that doesn't break the page completely): http://jsfiddle.net/anocpvb6/17/

Comment: I must say, I am using IE 11 on Windows 7 and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: It only get's broken if you click on the black area, but maybe you have a different build. for what it's worth we were able recreate this issue on multiple PCs.

Comment: Can you re-attach the click event listener in JavaScript at the end of each click handling function? It might be detaching after the attribute and therefore that DOM element is changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is a known IE bug. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796745/mouse-events-are-not-delivered-at-all-anymore-when-inside-an-svg-a-use-is-removed-from-the-dom

If you can, you should set `pointer-events: none;` for the use tag in your CSS. It's crazy, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Seems like this is the only real answer. Still so weird that Win8 IE is not affected, but the workaround works for my scenario!

Comment: I initially tried canceling pointer-events on the <svg> tag which did not work consistently. The <use> tag was the correct place for this fix, thanks!