# Changing the xlink:href in an svg <use> tag freezes all input in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I'm creating a log viewer with angularjs, which has to work in IE10.
Each list item has details which are collapsed. Clicking an SVG icon will expand the details.

Part of the HTML, with and without angularjs to change the icon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...  
  <body data-ng-app="listViewer">
    <div>
      <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
          <mask maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="arrowdwn">...</mask>
          <mask maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="arrowup">...</mask>
        </defs>

        <symbol id="expand">
          <circle class="expand" cx="10" cy="10" r=8 stroke-width="1" stroke="#dddddd" fill="#aaaaaa" mask="url(#arrowdwn)" />
        </symbol>

        <symbol id="collapse">
          <circle class="expand" cx="10" cy="10" r=8 stroke-width="1" stroke="#dddddd" fill="#aaaaaa" mask="url(#arrowup)" />
        </symbol>
      </svg>
    </div>
      ...
      <br /> This does <b>not</b> work in IE (switch the icon on click, using <b>angular.js</b>)
      <br /> It seems as if after the first click, all click events are removed (even on Plunker):
      <div class="item" data-ng-repeat="item in list.items">
        {{ item.name }}
        <svg width="20" height="20" data-ng-init="expand[item.id]=false" data-ng-click="expand[item.id] = !expand[item.id]">
          <use xlink:href="{{ expand[item.id] ? 'collapse' : 'expand' | svgIconHref }}" />
        </svg>
        <div class="detail" data-ng-show="expand[item.id]">
          list item details for {{ item.name }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br /> This does NOT work in IE (switch the icon on click, using <b>javascript setAttributeNS</b>)
      <br /> It seems as if after the first click, all click events are removed (even on Plunker):
      <div class="item" data-ng-repeat="item in list.items">
        {{ item.name }}
        <svg width="20" height="20" id="svg{{ item.id }}" onclick="javascript:expandcollapse(this);">
          <use id="icon{{ item.id }}" xlink:href="#expand" />
        </svg>
        <div id="details{{ item.id }}" class="detail" style="display: none">
          list item details for {{ item.name }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript:

```
(function() {
  var listViewer = angular.module('listViewer', []);

  // add a filter to allow concatenation of '#' and status for the svg 'use' href
  listViewer.filter('svgIconHref', function($sce) {
    return function(iconId) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('#' + iconId);
    };
  });

  listViewer.controller('listController', [function() {
    var list = this;
    list.items = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "first item"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "second item"
    }];
  }]);
}());


function expandcollapse(parent) {
  var id = parent.id.slice(-1);
  var icon = document.getElementById('icon' + id);
  var details = document.getElementById('details' + id);

  var hrf = icon.getAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href");
  hrf = hrf == '#expand' ? '#collapse' : '#expand';

  icon.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", hrf);
  details.style.display = hrf == "#expand" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

I've created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bN4VvNrSavQA3culSMDE?p=preview) to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

All options work in FF and Chrome, but in IE changing the xlink:href off the icon seems to remove all click events.

Any suggestions to get this working would be greatly appreciated.
For now I'm using a workaround that uses 2 icons and hides the one not used.
This will become a pain though when updating status icons which can have 5 flavors...

Cheers,
Mattie

Answer (score 0):

same as [Click events stop working after replacing attribute of <use> element in <svg> (Win7/IE11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149174/click-events-stop-working-after-replacing-attribute-of-use-element-in-svg-w)

their trick to use pointer-events: none did not work for me. i see no solution

Comment: If it's the same, flag it as a duplicate rather than answering it.