# xlink:href attribute of the "use" tag inside svg stops working sometimes in IE11

Tags: html, svg

In our code we are using constructions like:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#undo"></use></svg>
```

where "#undo" is

```
<svg>
    <symbol id="undo" viewBox="4 -4 24 24"><path d="M18 1c-2.6 0-4.7.7-7 3L8 1l-1 9 9-1-3-3s2-2 5-2c2.6 0 4.2 1.6 4 5-.1 1.9-.8 3.3-1 4l2 2s2-3 2-7c0-4.3-3-7-7-7z"/></symbol>
</svg>
```

in the same document.

This works almost in every browser. But for some reason it stops working after some DOM manipulations (deattaching and attaching back) in IE11 only. Can anybody light why this happens?

Unfortunately we haven't managed to reproduce it in small isolated sample. Probably somebody can direct me - where to look for, what attributes to check or something else. Any help highly appreciated.

#### Update 1

Some clarification: **in my case svg icon just desappears, icon content is not visible in spite of the svg element still in DOM and visible. I haven't told about mouse events.**

I've tried

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#undo" style="pointer-events: none;"></use></svg>
```

as suggested by @Robert Londson (in the [Click events stop working after replacing attribute of <use> element in <svg> (Win7/IE11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149174/click-events-stop-working-after-replacing-attribute-of-use-element-in-svg-w) thread) but this hasn't help.

Comment: @Robert Longson - why duplicate? The question is not about click events.

Comment: My mistake, but generally you should report bugs in IE to Microsoft.